# Como fazer um hover com link?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou precisando de uma ajuda em CSS, eu tenho meu carrossel e preciso que no *hover* aparece um link centralizado, atualmente eu deixei já como eu quero com o *hover*, ou seja, o *hover* esta em cima da imagem, segue o [link](http://planow.com.br/segredos-carne/pt/gourmet.php).

O *hover* é um *background* branco com opacidade e o *link*.

Comment: o ideal era disponibilizar um exemplo pequeno no http://JSFiddle.net, mas também gostaria de dizer que você deve especificar melhor o seu problema e a solução que você precisa, separadamente.

Comment: [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74) / [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Acredito que seja algo do tipo:

`$('.hover').mouseover(function(){
  var link = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
  $(this).append('<span class=temp>'+link+'</span>');
});
$('.hover').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.temp').remove();
});`

Comment: Experimente pesquisar por **[hover](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hover+is%3Aquestion)** no SOpt. Tem várias soluções prontas.

Comment: posta só o pedaço do código que tu quer mexer.

Comment: ´so naquela parte mesmo, do slider @haykou

Comment: dear lord... 45 perguntas e ainda com esses erros básicos ao perguntar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas com CSS dá pra fazer assim:

```css
.circulo{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
}

#texto-inside{
  display:none;
}

.circulo:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
.circulo:hover #texto-inside{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:35%;
  left:30%;
  font-size:20px;
  color:white;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="circulo">
  <p id="texto-inside">Macarrão</p>
</div>
```

Aí tu edita do jeito que quiser, poe um link no lugar do meu p, um transform no texto e tal.

Comment: obrigado, deu certo